# Exchange sync "Incorrect user name or password"

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, email, exchange

I am trying to connect a Samsung Galaxy S3 to an Exchange 2010 server for a client but it's causing me quite some grief. iPhones are connecting to this Exchange server without issue.

I receive the error message:

```
Incorrect user name or password
```

The following account details have been entered:

Domain\user name: clientdomain\username

Exchange server: mail.clientdomain.com.au

Use SSL: Have tried ticked & unticked

Can someone please help? I have Googled high & low lookingh for an answer but without any luck.